# Blender is just rendering a png I added as a plane instead of what the camera sees

Tags: rendering, image

When I press render, it doesn't render what the camera sees, but instead a png image that I added as a plane (specifically a very heavily edited picture of my face).

I made sure the camera is set to the actual camera in the scene settings, and not the png.

I've also tried moving, deleting and re-adding the camera and nothing has helped.

Here's a Gdrive link to the file: [intro.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PZ9h2j-9m0lZmfUaO2mcHXbbRTr3oqeC)

Comment: In the future please add images of your settings and add more information on your project instead of asking users to download your files.

Answer (score 2):

You have selected the png file to be the source for the output (composite)

[image]

Select the rendered result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry about not dding pictures, I didn't realize that was discouraged. I'll use that advice in the future. Unfortunately, doing this just results in a black screen being rendered.

Comment: You have to render, so that the compositor has information. Press F12 to have an image